# How to modify XML Tag value in java

Tags: java, regex, xml, tags

I have XML file data in String variable xmlDataString .Something like this data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Personnel_Details>
  <Employee_Type>
        <MY_Name>Seagull_AAAAA</MY_Name>
        <MY_LName>XXXXX</MY_LName>
  </Employee_Type>     
</Personnel_Details>
```

I want to replace "_" with "-" for only inside XML Tag ie  `<Personnel_Details>`  and not Seagull_AAAAA.So Output will be like

```
<Personnel-Details>
  <Employee-Type>
        <MY-Name>Seagull_AAAAA</MY-Name>
        <MY-LName>XXXXX</MY-LName>
   </Employee-Type> 
</Personnel-Details>
```

With below statement  it is changing   MY_Name to MY- Name and Seagull_AAAAA to Seagull-AAAAA.
I want only MY_Name to MY- Name to be change

```
xmlDataString = xmlDataString.replaceAll("_", "-");
```

This I want as generic,So I can apply to any XML Tag only ie another xml tag I have is like `<Company_Details> .....</Company_Details>`

Is any regular expression can be helpful here ?

Thanks in advance !!!!!

Comment: You are working with 'xml transformation (take one xml and create a new one from it)'. Please see tutorials https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html or dive into an example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803078/how-to-read-modify-fragments-of-xml-using-stax-in-java

Comment: Other option is XSLT (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html) ... but both paths are quite painful. Java xml transformation is not funniest part of java.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
xmlDataString = xmlDataString-replaceAll("(<[^>]*)_([^>]*>)", "$1-$2");
```

If there are tags with multiple underscores, you will need to run it multiple times...

Comment: Ohho that is so quick. This is what I looking for. Worked on Test class.  Now I will try in actual environment

Comment: Thanks Usagi Miyamoto. But what do u mean by run multiple times. In some of XML data I have tag like  <RQ_MOTOR_DTLS_CHANGED>N</RQ_MOTOR_DTLS_CHANGED><RQ_RATE_FROM_DATE>00000000</RQ_RATE_FROM_DATE>